# Why in C++ cout<<8*7/2 is giving 28?

Tags: c++

We know BODMAS rule or firstly according to priority, division will occur first. So **7/2 = 3**, as we are dividing **(int)/(int)**. then multiply by 8 , so **3*8** will be 24.

But `cout<<` is giving **28**.

Why this is happening?

Comment: `8*7/2` is the same as `(8*7)/2`, you can try `8*(7/2)`. See [C11 6.5.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5)

Comment: Please pick *one* language. C, C++ and Java aren't the same language, and may well have different rules.

Comment: "We know BODMAS rule or firstly according to priority, division will occur first." Only if the language follows the rules of BODMAS. Many programming languages have equal precedence for division and multiplication, with both having left-to-right associativity. In those languages, I'd expect a result of 28.

Comment: For C++ the operators follow [simple precedence rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). These do vary by language. `*` and `/` are both evaluated "left-to-right" at the same priority.

Comment: Never heard of BODMAS, but the descriptions I've found don't say "division before multiplication" but  has a step of "division and multiplication, going from left to right", which is what your program does.

Comment: https://i.paste.pics/87e3fcc6f47356465d0c4957d4a3968c.png

Comment: BOMDAS is either incorrect or incorrectly applied. Division and multiplication have the same priority, in programming as in mathematics. They are operated from left to right. The same for addition and subtraction (with lower priority than division and multiplication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ we not follow BODMAS strictly, `+ -` has less priority than `* /`. But `+` and `-` has same priority. It means one which will appear first from left to right will be evaluated first. Similary `* /` has same priority.

So  `cout << 8*7/2 ;` is eqivalent to  `cout << 56/2 ;`. Because `* /` both has same priority but `*` appeared first, so `*` is evaluated first.

And to achieve what you want you can use `cout << 8*(7/2) ;`.

Comment: C++ works the same as all the descriptions of BODMAS that I've found. First brackets, then orders, then division *and* multiplication going from left to right, then addition *and* subtraction going from left to right.

Comment: in math multiplication and division has always have the same precedence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BODMAS

Comment: "Appeared first" is not the technically correct wording, `*` and `/` have the same precedence and left to right associativity: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Note that C++ does not strictly guarantee left-to-right _evaluation_. C++ uses precedence to build an evaluation tree. Once built, that tree can even be evaluated in parallel.

Answer (score 5):

> We know BODMAS rule or firstly according to priority, division will occur first.

Well, no. To my kwnoledge (see e.g. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics) or [2](https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-bodmas.html)), BODMAS stands for

> **B** Brackets first
> **O** Orders (i.e. Powers and Square Roots, etc.)
> **DM** Division **and** Multiplication (**left-to-right**)
> **AS** Addition and Subtraction (left-to-right)

So that `8*7/2` would be processed as `(8*7)/2`.

Answer (score 2):

In math the order in which the multiplication and the division are done do not matter as you work with real numbers. and `(8*7)/2` is the same as `8*(7/2)`

In C (or C++) integer arithmetic however things _are_different. The multiplication and division operator have the same precedence and are left associative. That means that `8*7/2` is interpreted as `(8*7)/2`, which in this case gives answer that corresponds with real math. So while mathematically `7/2*8` is equal to `8*7/2` it will be very different in C as it is governed by different rules. Computers don't do real numbers.

So yes in computer (integer) arithmetic it *does* matter in which order you do things.